# Swift UITextField: Create a dynamically decrease UITextField Frame in autolayout

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, uitextfield

I am using Custom Cell in UITableView. And the basic model of the cell is as follows.

[image]

I would like to have the dashed line dynamically deformed according to the size of the Menu Name box in this cell. So I wrote the following code:

```
menuField.frame.size.width = getWidth(text: menuField.text!)
            menuField.layoutIfNeeded()
            dotLine.layoutIfNeeded()

func getWidth(text: String) -> CGFloat {
        let txtField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        txtField.text = text
        txtField.sizeToFit()
        return txtField.frame.size.width
    }
```

This worked very well. Only increase if only! If the Menu Name Frame is reduced below the currently set size, the size remains unchanged.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, I need to make not only the size of the dotted line increase but also the shrinkage. I do not know what my problem is. Please help me!

Comment: Do you want to have same number of dots every time?

Comment: No. The number of dots does not matter. The number of points does not matter. I only need to keep the distance between the Menu Text box and the dotted line constant.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of code you wrote, autolayout does this for you. Just set autolayout like this:

*Dash is constraint with your value*

**- MenuTextField - Dotted line - Price -**

Comment: I am really sorry. My question seems to have been misplaced. I want the spacing between Menu Text Box and dotted lines to be constant.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. First, I added the width dimension Constraints of the Menu Text Box and imported it into the IBOutlet variable.

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And I changed the value of the variable according to the text length.

```
menuWidth.constant = getWidth(text: menuField.text!)
```

This method is not yet fully functional. But it works the way I want.

Also thanks to Robert Dresler who answered me :) Thanks!